# How to make a readonly xa datasource connection to mysql server on jboss

Tags: mysql, jboss, readonly, xa

it is clear in the title, I would be great if you share your experience about it.

I tried that but didn't work..

```
...
    <xa-datasource>    
    <jndi-name>DSReadOnly</jndi-name>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class> 
    .
    ..
    <xa-datasource-property name="readOnly">true</xa-datasource-property>
     ..
     .

</xa-datasource>
```

Comment: What did you try and what means "did not work"?

Comment: did you read the title? I want to make a READ-ONLY connection to mysql using xa datasource running on jboss.. I tried to add the readOnly attribute as you see above, however it did not work, in other words it was not a read-only connection, moreover, I was able to write to db.

Comment: Yes, I did read the title. But you never said, that it was not a read-only connection. "Did not work" can mean a lot of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define access privileges on the database level, not in datasource.

Comment: Thanks. So you say it is impossible without the database level?

Answer (score 2):

According to Mysql documentation there is no such properties like `readOnly`:

[Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

And also I cannot find any information about such properties in Mysql JDBC Driver. You can check sources for properties interface here: [ConnectionProperties](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Database-JDBC-Connection-Pool/mysql/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionProperties.java.html).